# Is it Possible to use TryGetValue on deep nested dictionary?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net, trygetvalue

I want to access a certain property on a dictionary safelay with the TryGetValue-method.

For example an entry i would directly access like this:

```
jsonObject[prop1][prop2][0][prop3]
```

Is there any convenient way to do so?

Comment: What do you expect it to do if the value does not exist? And what type is `jsonObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea (untested). It does assume a nested `IDictionary` at least as deep as the number of keys specified, and works in `object` (you could of course do things to make this a generic):

```
bool TryGetNestedValue (this IDictionary dict, out object value, 
    params object[] keys)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
    {
        var key = keys[i];

        if (!dict.Contains(key))
        {
            value = null;
            return false;
        }

        if (i == keys.Length - 1)
        {
            value = dict[key];
            return true;
        }

        dict = dict[key];
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("keys");
}
```